# Imported Private Certificates cannot be linked to Api Gateway in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-certificate-manager

We are thinking of using our own Private Certificate Authority within AWS. Using the information provided [here](https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/) were able to create a private certificate and import it into ACM. However when we try to refer this private certificate when creating a Custom Domain in ApiGateway(via terraform) we get an error that the certificate does not exist. If we try to create the custom domain via the AWS console, the certificate doesnt show up at all.. Do certificates have any iam policy associated with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACM's [Private Certificate Authority](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm-pca/latest/userguide/PcaWelcome.html) is only for internal use within your company:

> This service is for enterprise customers building a public key infrastructure (PKI) inside the AWS cloud and intended for **private use within an organization**

> Certificates issued by a private CA are trusted only within your organization, **not on the internet**.

You can't use them on API Gateway. For that you require public certificates which you can get for free from ACM.

If your private certificate is managed by ACM, you [should be able](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/private-certificate-authority/?nc=sn&loc=6) to use it on API gateway:

> With **ACM Private CA** you can choose to **delegate certificate management** to ACM for certificates used with ACM-integrated services, such as Elastic Load Balancing and **API Gateway**.

Comment: Thanks for responding. We're using this on a private rest api via a vpc endpoint. Can we use our own private ca within AWS or is that not allowed

Comment: @MadhavShenoy I updated the answer. In short yes, it should be possible, on condition that your private CA is managed by ACM.